# assert collection does not contain item

Tags: java, hamcrest

Using the hamcrest library for Java, what's a nicely readable way to do the opposite of:

```
assertThat(someCollection, hasItem(someItem))
```

I want to make sure `someCollection` does not contain item `someItem`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Negate the `hasItem` assertion

```
assertThat(someCollection, not(hasItem(someItem)))
```

Comment: Once I imported the package IsNot (`import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not`) it worked well.

Comment: The `Matcherzs` defines all of the. factory methods so you can have a single `*` static import. I'll look it up a work if no one else posts the line in the next hour.

Comment: @harschware - From the [basic tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial), `import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;` and `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;`

Comment: In hamcrest version 1.3-  
assertThat(someCollection, not(hasItem(someItem))) didn't work so I used
assertThat(someCollection, not(contains(someItem)))

Answer (score 7):

If you need to Assert an Array, the same logic use `not(hasItemInArray())`

```
final String[] availableIds = {"123", "321"};
final String userId = "333";

softAssert.assertThat("Id not found", availableIds, not(hasItemInArray(userId)));
softAssert.assertAll();
```

Answer (score -3):

or you can do;

```
.extract().jsonPath().getObject("data", pojo.class);  
(above is response)

assertThat(response, not(hasItem(bodyYouArePosting)));
```